# How can we upload common images only to AWS S3 using WordPress?

Tags: images, plugin-recommendation

There are multiple plugins for uploading images to AWS S3 and Cloudfront from WordPress but none has the features to restrict by post type. I want to upload only common images which are to be shared in various platforms.

We can do it by directly uploading through AWS Panel but any suggestions from WordPress?

Regards

Ankit

Comment: How would such a plugin determine which images you consider “common”? That’s not an attribute images normally have in WordPress.

Comment: This sounds like a question to ask the authors of the plugin you like best - they'd hopefully have an 'upload this image or not' hook you can filter.